# Loading app.config in a multiple project gets nullpointer exception

Tags: c#, app-config

I have a solution with projects:
Utilities
MainProject

where Utilities is used by MainProject, and MainProject is the main dll that I am using.

I have a app.config for each project. In particular, my Utilities project automatically places its app.config in Utilities\bin\debug\ folder. In my code, I am trying to access it from:

```
private static Configuration UConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath);
```

or

```
private static Configuration UConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(typeof(UtilitiesConfiguration).Assembly.Location);
```

but obviously they both give same null pointer exception error when I am trying to access the configuration.

When I print out the FilePath of the Configuration, it shows it is trying to load this configuration from MainProject\bin\debug where all dlls eventually goes to, but the Utilities' app.config apparently didn't get copied over.

What is the best approach to fix this issue?

Comment: It's been quite a while since I had this kind of need so I'm not sure, but AFAIK DLLs rely on the .config file of the application... I'll leave a proper answer to more knowlegeable folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main application.config is where you application will read the config from. the other configs are not looked at.

What are you trying to do and maybe there is a better solution using a class made up of  ConfigurationElements and a custom Section

if you make the utilities application read from the utilities.config file you will cause confusion later on when another developer tries to edit the config or needs to debug and they will only look in the main applications config.  it is just not a standard from my experieince

Comment: so the standard way to do it is to put them in the MainProject's app.config? I just did it that way because some attributes are only used in Utilities. wouldn't putting everything in a single config file creates a huge file?

Comment: actually using app.config in multiple projects is not a good design(at least in my case), I should've used only 1 app.config and in other places instead of using values from app.config I should pass in values from class initialization.

Comment: you app.config can become huge if you have a lot of values that need to be changed without re-compile. for situations where you may be sending out to different clients or users.  Web.configs act the same way.  if you have a lot of items that you are reading in please look at configurationElelments.  I can send or post an example here if you need.

Comment: thanks for following up! although my question is solved by restructuring the usage of app.config, an example on ConfigurationElements is definitely a great help and is another solution to this situation too!